# Which spelling is the right one: "deinstallieren" or "desinstallieren"?

Tags: word-choice, spelling

Some computer software uninstallers that are localized for German users use the word *"deinstallieren"* and others *"desinstallieren"*.

Which one is the correct one - or are both words right?

--

**Update**

The [Duden spell checking software/service](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibpruefung-online) seems to accept both words. But I don't trust it.

[image: Desinstallieren]

Comment: Could you please add a *link* to the spell checking service?

Comment: @thei done. on that page you have to click the "Text überprüfen" tab – it's a little confusing.

Comment: This is interesting. The spellchecker has more words than the dictionary. I tried "überwuzeln" and "unterwuchern", and the spellchecker knows überwuzeln which the dictionary does not, but it does not accept unterwuchern (as it would if it just decomposed prefixes). So maybe Desinstallieren (which is absolutely wrong to my feeling) has been included by popular demand.

Comment: @thei: Do you really mean _überwuzeln_? Then I wonder why this would be included.

Comment: @Hendrik http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-7272-at-(etwas)+%C3%BCberwuzelt+sein.html *sich im fortgeschritten Alter befinden* :)

Comment: @splattne: Thanks! I've never seen or heard that before.

Comment: @Hendrik: I *tried* to enter a word that is unlikely to be in the duden, so it is not too surprising that you don't know it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deinstallieren/Deinstallation is correct - the confusion might come from Desinformieren/Desinformation (disinformation)

Comment: Hm, the spelling checker in MS Word recognizes both "deinstallieren" and "desinstallieren" as correct.

Comment: @splattne: Maybe I'm prejudiced but I'd consider that one of the least trustworthy sources. Duden for example doesn't know about *desinstallieren*.

Comment: @musiKk http://i.imgur.com/DM6Hu.png (Duden online spell checker)

Comment: @splattne: http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/desinstallieren - http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/deinstallieren - See the difference?

Comment: @John okay, thanks! It just seems that the (online) Duden orthography software doesn't use its own vocabulary.

Comment: I think this has something to do with spell checkers allowing combinations of certain words and syllables. Especially for German that's important because you can create a huge number of words but a dictionary can only contain so many.

Comment: I had the same idea, but I couldn't find another accepted word starting in des-.

Comment: @splattne: You can't? I can hardly find words that are not accepted. *Deskorrigieren*, *Desprüfen*, *Dessuchen*, *Deslieben*, *Deslernen*, *Desbauen*, *Desarbeit*, *Despresse*, *Deshandel*... they are all accepted.

Comment: @splattne duden.de lists the two examples _desarmieren_ and _desinfizieren_ (links contained in my answer below).

Answer (score 5):

A Google search indicates that *desinstallieren* is a spelling mistake: Searching for [*desinstallieren*](http://www.google.de/#q=%2Bdesinstallieren) yields about 10,000 results, whereas [*deinstallieren*](http://www.google.de/#q=%2Bdeinstallieren) yields almost 5,000,000 results, which is a factor of 500. Moreover, if you type in *desinstallieren*, it auto-corrects and offers *deinstallieren*.

Comment: I went to the Duden Online orthography checker. Both words seem to be accepted: http://i.imgur.com/DM6Hu.png -- Update: It even accepts *Disinstallation* and *Dissinstallation!*

Comment: @splattne: So you say it accepts almost anything? Seems rather useless to me ...

Comment: hm... yes, my trust in that site certainly has been shaken.

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

duden.de lists the same meanings for the prefixes [de-](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/de_) and [des-](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/des__Verneinung) as:

> (1.) drückt in Bildungen mit Verben aus, dass etwas aufgehoben, rückgängig gemacht wird
>
> (...)

But I agree with Hendrik Vogt and Hackworth that *deinstallieren* is the correct one, I don't think I've ever seen *desinstallieren* used in my 25 years as a programmer.

Comment: I disagree with your conclusion. It is certainly not "technically" correct to apply the prefix *des-* to some word even if it sounds half-way right and call it a day. It's the other way around: If a word does have this prefix, *then* it means whatever you said above.

Comment: @musiKk I guess you have a point there, I removed that sentence.