# What defines the use of the "in-/un-" prefix for building the inversion?

Tags: prefix

*inexakt*, but *ungenau*. Is this pure convention or are there any rules of thumb what prefix to choose when building an inversion of an adjective (for example pronunciation)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A pretty good rule of thumb is whether the word to be negated is a *Fremdwort* or not. Latin words are inverted with *in-*, Greek words are negated with *a-*, while typical German words are inverted with *un-*.

Examples:

- Inexakt, indiskutabel, inakzeptabel, invariant, inoperabel
- ungenau, unmöglich, unwohnlich, unbehaglich, unversehrt, unverletzt, unbeschädigt, undenkbar, unfreundlich, unnahbar, unverschlossen

As usual, this is not a 100% rule. For example "Natur" is latin as well, but *natürlich* is negated to *unnatürlich*, because of the *-lich* suffix, which is typical for a German word.

Also note that you should avoid the un-prefix where possbile, for stylistic reasons. Almost all un-words can be expressed by an alternative word, without changing the rest of the sentence.

Some articles:

1. [This first link is the best to answer your question](http://faql.de/wortgebrauch.html#verneinung), it also covers the *a-* negation and where *in-* turns to *il-*.
2. [A blog posting arguing to avoid the un-words](http://juttas-schreibtipps.blogspot.com/2006/09/ber-un-wrter.html).
3. [Examples for words starting with *un-*](http://www.gfds.de/publikationen/der-sprachdienst/aufloesungen-aelterer-preisaufgaben/woerter-mit-der-vorsilbe-iun-i/) that are not negations or that do not have an equivalent word without the un-.

Comment: Manchmal geht auch beides, z.B. "unakzeptabel".

Comment: 'unakzeptabel' halte ich für inakzeptabel.

Comment: Der Duden ist da aber anderer Meinung.

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/which-spelling-is-the-right-one-deinstallieren-or-desinstallieren

Der Duden hat viele komische Meinungen, wie's aussieht. Siehe die Kommentare unter Henrik Vogts Antwort. Abgesehen davon: Ja, man würde 'unakzeptabel' verstehen, man muss es aber nicht schön finden

Comment: @Hackworth: Man muss da den Online-Duden von der Online-Rechtschreibprüfung des Duden unterscheiden. Letztere ist ein Witz, z.B. wird _Dissinstallation_ (mit zwei 2 _s_!) akzeptiert. Aber der Online-Duden an sich erscheint mir recht zuverlässig. (Man darf natürlich trotzdem eine gesunde Skepsis nie aufgeben!)

Answer (score 1):

in- is used in Latin. Roughly: if the adjective has a Latin origin, we use in-, if not, we use un-.